# Difference between %S and %s in lua

Tags: lua

According to the book, this part of code is dividing a line in 2 parts, I do not understand the difference between %S and %s ,neither how exactly is it dividing it in two parts.

```
local namefrom, nameto = string.match(line, "(%S+)%s+(%S+)")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html), %s means whitespace, and %S means anything other than whitespace.  So that match expression will split on one or more whitespace characters, capturing the two strings on either side.